# Using USB-C charger D+ and D- pins for comms with an STM32 chip

Tags: usb, battery-charging, usb-c

I'm looking at the [MAX77751](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/power/battery-management/MAX77751.html/) single cell Li-Ion and LiPo charger chip that features both USB-C and USB 2.1 detection. The battery would power a design that uses an [STM32L433CCUx](https://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers-microprocessors/stm32l433cc.html) chip which has another USB 2.1 connector for comms. Can I use the D+ and D- pins from the USB-C receptacle for communication with the STM32 chip as well? If yes, would I need to disconnect the D+ and D- pins from the MAX77751?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer, no.

This chip uses D+/D- pin specifically for the USB-C power negotiation in order to get higher voltage, this means the chip actively communicates over these lines, thereof, you can't plug an STM32 there.

You would need a chip that is acting like a hub or bypass to be able to communicate upstream.

Alternatively, you could use a chip like MAX77961 (or alike) and then do the power negotiation with the STM32 (if it supports it)